# Validación de campos con Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, bootstrap

Estoy usando la clase `has-error` para validar que no deje registrar si algún campo no ha sido llenado.

Este es el resultado al querer registrar si marca en rojo los campos, pero me debe de mostrar una etiqueta donde diga `"No puedes dejar campos en blanco"` el cual no me aparece

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Además aparece un error en esta línea.

```
 document.getElementById("mensajeErrorCampos").style.display = "block";
```

Con este mensaje.

```
 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null
```

En la función registrar de JS tengo este código.

Primero estoy tomando el valor de cada uno de los campos y luego comparo si están en blanco si es asi, deberia de lanzar el mensaje y marcarlos en rojo (esto ya lo hace).

```js
var itemDes =document.getElementById("itemDes").value;
var price =document.getElementById("price").value;
var manufacturer =document.getElementById("manufacturer").value;
var model =document.getElementById("model").value;
var min =document.getElementById("min").value;
var max =document.getElementById("max").value;
var engineer =document.getElementById("engineer").value;
var category =document.getElementById("category").value;
var location =document.getElementById("location").value;
var supplier =document.getElementById("supplier").value;
var unit =document.getElementById("unit").value;
var item =document.getElementById("item").value;
if(itemDes === '' || price === '' || manufacturer === '' || model === '' || min === '' || max === '' || engineer === '' || category === ''  || location === ''|| supplier === ''|| unit === '' || item === '')
{
 // $("#mensajeErrorCampos").text("No puede dos departamentos con el mismo nombre " + el.value);
 $("#itemDes").parent().addClass('has-error');
 $("#price").parent().addClass('has-error');
 $("#manufacturer").parent().addClass('has-error');
 $("#model").parent().addClass('has-error');
 $("#min").parent().addClass('has-error');
 $("#max").parent().addClass('has-error');
 $("#engineer").parent().addClass('has-error');
 $("#category").parent().addClass('has-error');
 $("#location").parent().addClass('has-error');
 $("#supplier").parent().addClass('has-error');
 $("#unit").parent().addClass('has-error');
 $("#item").parent().addClass('has-error');
 document.getElementById("mensajeErrorCampos").style.display = "block";
 document.getElementById("mensajeErrorCampos").innerHTML = "No puedes dejar campos en blanco";
 document.location.href="#mensajeErrorCampos";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He resulto mi problema dejo la solucion por si ha alguien mas le esta pasando esto. 
En mi html y dentro del modal agregue.

```
 <div class="alert alert-danger" style="display: none" id="errorMessage"></div>
```

Y en esta parte le cambie al id que le indique.

```
document.getElementById("errorMessage").style.display = "block";
```